# Share window created in Qt C++ with PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt

If another program (written in C++) creates windows using Qt, is there any way for the developer of that program to make them available to another program which uses the PyQt bindings?  For example, can the C++ program broadcast QWindow or QApplication handles somehow so that it can be operated on by the PyQt program?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at the sip module that's behind PyQt

`sip.wrapinstance`/`sip.unwrapinstance`

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html

You also need to bind your C++ program to Python, I'd personally recommend Boost.Python here.